# OPenshift uploaded files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift

i have a problem. I uploaded some files and after some time they were deleted.Is it Ok becouse i use free version openshift and wildFly?
path to uploaded servletContext.getRealPath("/uploaded_images/")
the folder uploaded_images in src/main/webapp/uploaded_images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're not using the [`$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#directory-variables) for storing persistent data. Sotring uploaded files elsewhere means they will be deleted with the next code push (deployment), unless they are in the repository itself (which they should not be).

Check [this article](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html#__code_data_code) for more details about the data dir. Note that it can be used with non-scaling applications only.